# how to can create graph in c# for dijkstra algorithm?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, dictionary

I'm writing dijkstra algorithm,i want to create list of neighbors for each node i am writing a little bit code but my code doesn't create list of neighbors for each node.
it has a problem that doesn't distinct neighbors for each node and that's why keeps totally list of neighbors for each node.

for example: Node[id] ==> (neighbor,weight)

```
Node[0] ==> (1,123)
Node[0] ==> (2,113)
Node[0] ==> (3,214)
Node[0] ==> (4,203)

Node[1] ==> (2,175)
Node[1] ==> (4,214)
```

[image]

---

```
    public class Graph
{
    public Dictionary<int, List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>> vertices = new Dictionary<int, List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>>();

    public void AddVertex(int id, List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> edges)
    {
        vertices[id] = edges;
    }
}
```

---

```
    private Graph g = new Graph();

    public int Id { get; set; }
    private List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> dic = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();

    private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            var result = circleManager.HitTest(e.Location);
            if (result != -1)
            {
                circlesSourceAndDestination.Add(circleManager.Circles[result]);

                if (Count == 1)
                {
                    Id = result;
                }
                else if (Count == 2)
                {
                    var weigth = CalculateLengthSourceAndDestination(circlesSourceAndDestination);
                    circlesSourceAndDestination.Clear();
                    if (weigth < 0)
                    {
                        weigth *= -1;
                    }

                    dic.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(result, weigth));
                    g.AddVertex(Id, dic);
                    //neighborList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(result, weigth));
                    //newNode.Neighbors = neighborList;

                    //graph.Add(newNode);

                    Count = 0;
                }
                Count++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var result = circleManager.HitTest(e.Location);
            if (result != -1)
            {
                circleManager.Circles[circleManager.HitTest(e.Location)].Selected = true;
                circleManager.Circles[result].SelectFillColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what goes wrong a little more. Your code is fine and relatively readable, but it's hard to understand what is actually going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dic` field is getting updated during each iteration. This is why all the vertices have the same neighbors. You need to refactor your code and create a new list of neighbors.

```
public class Graph
{
    public Dictionary<int, List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>> vertices = new Dictionary<int, List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>>();

    public void AddVertex(int id, List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> edges)
    {
        if(!vertices.ContainsKey(id))
        {
              vertices.Add(id, new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>());
        }
        vertices[id].AddRange(edges);
    }
}

public int Id { get; set; }

private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        var result = circleManager.HitTest(e.Location);
        if (result != -1)
        {
            circlesSourceAndDestination.Add(circleManager.Circles[result]);

            if (Count == 1)
            {
                Id = result;
            }
            else if (Count == 2)
            {
                var weigth = CalculateLengthSourceAndDestination(circlesSourceAndDestination);
                circlesSourceAndDestination.Clear();
                if (weigth < 0)
                {
                    weigth *= -1;
                }
                var neighbor = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(result, weigth);
                var list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> { neighbor };
                g.AddVertex(Id, list);


                Count = 0;
            }
            Count++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var result = circleManager.HitTest(e.Location);
        if (result != -1)
        {
            circleManager.Circles[circleManager.HitTest(e.Location)].Selected = true;
            circleManager.Circles[result].SelectFillColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

You get the idea... (I can't test this code)